# python 3 print with extra characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following section to print the **ant** build info into a file.

```
rsltFile = open('buildLog.txt', 'w')
    p = subprocess.Popen('call ant compile', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in p.stdout.readlines(): 
        rsltFile.write("%s\n" % line) 
        print(line)
    retval = p.wait()
```

It worked fine in **python 2.6** but it print out some extra character for each line in **python 3.2**, like this following:

```
b'Buildfile: C:\\workspace\\VCT2400_Service\\ServiceApplication\\build.xml\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'init:\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'clean:\r\n'
b'    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\\workspace\\VCT2400_Service\\ServiceApplication\\classes\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'compile:\r\n'
b'    [javac] Compiling 492 source files to C:\\workspace\\VCT2400_Service\\ServiceApplication\\classes\r\n'
```

Those **b'** and **\r\n'** are extra, not expect them there.

Comment: `.readlines()` is redundant here (and probably less efficient, as I believe it will build the entire list of output lines before it starts iterating); you can just treat the file object itself as an iterator.

Comment: how to do that? I am new to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files opened in text mode expect strings to be written into them. You get byte objects from `readlines()` which are converted to string representation by format `%` operator.

Open the file in binary mode and dump lines there directly:

```
rsltFile = open('buildLog.txt', 'wb')
...
rsltFile.write(line + b'\n')
```

...or, interpret subprocess output as a string:

```
linestr = line.decode('utf8')
```

P.S. It looks like adding '\n' is not needed, each `line` already ends with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Or try adding this `universal_newlines=True` to the Popen class contructor.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('call ant compile', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
```